# php - create file not working

Tags: php, file, mkdir, file-put-contents

I have this PHP script that is supposed to create an article when you fill out a form. I go the code from various sources combined but it does not seem to work. The code does not report any errors but when I try to go to `http://somesite.com/article/article-name` it gives me a 404

Code:

```
if (isset($_POST['title']) && isset($_POST['content'])) {
    if(!file_exists(dirname('/article/' . str_replace(' ', '-', $_POST['title'])))) {
        mkdir(dirname('/article/' . str_replace(' ', '-', $_POST['title'])), 0777, true);
        touch('/article/' . str_replace(' ', '-', $_POST['title']) . '/index.php');
        file_put_contents('/article/' . str_replace(' ', '-', $_POST['title']) . '/index.php', $_POST['content']);
    }
}
```

Any ideas on what is going wrong? All help appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Comment: @FrankerZ I edited it, I hope that helps.

Comment: 404 seems to indicate that it's not getting to your script properly. Perhaps a mod rewrite issue?

Answer (score 0):

OK guys. I made the script work by getting rid of all the `dirname`'s!

Final Code:

```
if (isset($_POST['title']) && isset($_POST['content'])) {
    if(!file_exists(str_replace(' ', '-', $_POST['title']))) {
        mkdir(str_replace(' ', '-', $_POST['title']), 0777, true);
        touch(str_replace(' ', '-', $_POST['title']) . '/index.php');
        file_put_contents(str_replace(' ', '-', $_POST['title']) . '/index.php', $_POST['content']);
        echo "article made!";
    } else {
        echo "article not made! " . str_replace(' ', '-', $_POST['title']);
    }
} else {
    echo "article not made! " . str_replace(' ', '-', $_POST['title']);
}
```

Comment: why did you have the `dirname()` calls in the first place?

Comment: @FKEinternet I copied the code from a website, it had them so I kept them

Comment: Welcome to The Real World(tm) where freely available code has no guarantees - *always* check your work, even if the work was borrowing from somewhere else ...